# Swagger Edtior Post Request Example:  Could not render n, see the console

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I'm having trouble rendering an example request body in openapi. I've distilled it down to this simple example:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: Test
  version: "1"
paths:
  /Users:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            example: 
              name: "John"
              
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Fetches them
          content:
            application/json:
              example:
                - name: John Doe
```

https://editor.swagger.io/# and a few other tools can't seem to render the Request body. All I get is:

`Could not render n, see the console.`

Although, the response body renders fine as expected.

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: It's a Swagger UI bug caused by `requestBody.content.application/json` having no `schema`. Please open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly i am not sure why you want to add only example without schema, yes we can say its a kind of bug in swagger-ui,

See the console error in swagger editor,

```
swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:33 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJS' of undefined
    at c (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:33)
    at t.default (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:33)
    at n.value (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:33)
    at n.R.t.render (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:33)
    at u._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:100)
    at u._renderValidatedComponent (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:100)
    at u.performInitialMount (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:100)
    at u.mountComponent (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:100)
    at Object.mountComponent (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:13)
    at u.performInitialMount (swagger-editor-bundle.js:sourcemap:100)
```

---

This is strange its working when specify schema type in `requestBody`, it will help you for temporary fix, like this,

```yaml
requestBody:
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        type: object
      example: 
        name: "John"
```

For more details [Media Type Specification](https://swagger.io/specification/#media-type-object)

Comment: Thanks, this gets me over the line, although I don't understand why the schema is required to display the example, I assume its a bug

Comment: Yes i have updated answer, you are right, i reviewed these kind of errors in swagger ui github today, realized this is a kind of bug in swagger-ui.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved as there was some extra space in my openapi.yml. I removed that space and got it resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).